# How do I create a file like object that can return an arbitrarily large amount of repeating data?

Tags: python, file, inheritance, subprocess

For use with subprocess.run's stdin argument, I am trying to create a file like object that will return the same sequence of either characters or bytes as many times as I like. I would like it to look something like this:

```
>>>file_like3 = FileLike("Repeating sequence\n", 3)
>>>print(file_like3.read())
Repeating sequence
Repeating sequence
Repeating sequence

>>>file_like5 = FileLike("print('print through subprocess')\n", 5)
>>>p = subprocess.run(["python"], stdin = file_like5, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
>>>print(p.stdout)
b'print through subprocess\nprint through subprocess\nprint through subprocess\nprint through subprocess\nprint through subprocess'
```

I would like to do this so that I can emulate a file of arbitrary length without actually creating or reading the file. Since I need this as an input to subprocess.run, I think doing something similar but extending bytearray instead of a file object would work for me as well. It seems like I would need to overwrite whichever methods subprocess.run uses from the file or bytearray object, but I have no idea how to figure out which methods those are.

Comment: See the [File Object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) documentation for the methods you might need to implement. How many you actually need to define depend on what your use case requires. Start with the basics (e.g. `read()`) and expand as needed.

Comment: @glibdud I tried overriding read(), readline(), readlines(), next(), and iter() with a print statement and a call to the super's method, and none of them seemed to be called. Those seemed to be the most likely methods to be used by subprocess.run, so I'm not sure how it is using the file object.